# Windows are graying out fairly often in Ubuntu 15.10, help?

Tags: unity, firefox, 15.10, gui

No, this isn't for any specific program (as the suggested other questions are), this is in general. I will be attempting a task and the window will just gray out and become unresponsive for a while. For example, just now while typing this, I decided to check through my installed applications and firefox, the only thing running at the time, went unresponsive. But this isn't just firefox. This is the unity tweak tool, it's the settings menu, it's the file explorer (or whatever the general name for that is), etc. The only thing I can think of that hasn't done this is the terminal. The CPU usage doesn't seem to be consistently high either. Speaking of CPU, it's an 8-core 3.whatever gigahertz AMD FX series processor. This should not be happening. So, with the symptoms described, what's the diagnosis? Do I need X, Y, and Z drivers? Do I need to enable some setting in a deeply buried XML file?

Comment: I would first check `System Settings > Details ` & see whats listed for Graphics. If it shows `llvmpipe`  then performance will be terrible. In that case look for drivers for your video hardware whether it's integrated or discreet (you didn't mention.

Comment: Graphics is an NVIDIA card whose proprietary driver I have installed, defaulted, and updated. So I would not imagine that being the source of the issue.